# how do i detect the current position in vlc video-playback in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, media-player, vlc, libvlc

how do i detect the current position in vlc video-playback in vb.net?

Basically as the clip is playing, I want in a label for it to say "02:58/21:35" relating to the current clip being played.

So I'll need to somehow figure out how to detect current position and end position. Does anyone know how to do this?

Code so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Paused As Boolean = False
    Dim Started As Boolean = False
    Dim PlayedSecond As Boolean = True
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PlayedSecond = False
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("https://vula.uct.ac.za/access/content/group/fe879ca4-927a-4fca-9cc9-33b12c348b37/vids/Lessig-ItIsAboutTimeGettingOurValuesAroundCopyright522.flv")
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
        Started = True
    End Sub

    Sub playsecond()
            AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
            AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("http://lsta2011.wikispaces.com/file/view/Rogue%20Waves.mp4")
            AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
            PlayedSecond = True
            Started = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub AxVLCPlugin21_pause(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AxVLCPlugin21.pause
            Paused = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub IsFinished_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IsFinished.Tick
        If Not AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.isPlaying And Paused = False And Started = True And PlayedSecond = False Then
            playsecond()
            Started = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AxVLCPlugin21_play(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AxVLCPlugin21.play
        Paused = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin), you can get the current position and the length of the video by reading the following properties:

- `AxVLCPlugin21.input.time` to get the current position.
- `AxVLCPlugin21.input.length` which contains the length of the video.

Both these properties are in milliseconds; you will have to convert them by yourself in hours, minutes and seconds.